# DbSet.Where() Returning No Records on Query Even When They Exist in Dataset

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

Okay, so I'm going crazy here. I've used DbSet.Where's 1000 times and for whatever reason it's not working in this particular xunit test. The issue seems to be rooted with my where statement trying to get a list of recipeid's = 1 so I can delete them. Whe I stop th ecode and look at my locals the params are set to 1 where designated, but the where won't pick it up.

I've consolidated the code a bit to make it more readable here, but it still doesn't work as is. What the heck am I missing?

```cs
[Fact]
        public void DeleteIngredientListWithId_ReturnsProperCount()
        {
            //Arrange
            var dbOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<IngredientDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: $"IngredientDb{Guid.NewGuid()}")
                .Options;
            var sieveOptions = Options.Create(new SieveOptions());

            var fakeIngredientOne = new Ingredient { RecipeId = 1 };
            var fakeIngredientTwo = new Ingredient { RecipeId = 1 };
            var fakeIngredientThree = new Ingredient { RecipeId = 2 };

            //Act
            using (var context = new IngredientDbContext(dbOptions))
            {
                context.Ingredients.AddRange(fakeIngredientOne, fakeIngredientTwo, fakeIngredientThree);

                var service = new IngredientRepository(context, new SieveProcessor(sieveOptions));

                var ingredients = context.Ingredients.Where(i => i.RecipeId == 1).ToList();
                context.Ingredients.RemoveRange(ingredients);
                context.SaveChanges();

                //Assert
                var ingredientList = context.Ingredients.ToList();

                ingredientList.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(fakeIngredientThree);
                ingredientList.Should().HaveCount(1);

                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might not be persisting the records you added to the database before you subsequently try to query (and then remove them). The `Where` method is looking at the database, which is empty until you `SaveChanges()`

Until you save the changes, the pending additions are probably waiting for you in `context.Ingredients.Local`